# umask XXX (permission bits) to give execute permission to files

Tags: permissions, exec, umask

Because files created by default having permission of 666 and `umask` (in permission bits form) subtract bit-wise from this permission, can we do something to give `execute` permission without using permission character (r,w,x) ?

I am refering to using bit-wise mask, e.g

```
umask 002
```

not setting permission character such as

```
umask u+x
umask u=rwx
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. `umask` only prevents permissions but never adds them. Thus you get execute permission only if the creating `open()` syscall does contain them. This is the case if a compiler creates an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

The permission of a new file is computed from the permission used with the `creat()` call.

You `umask` results in:

```
$ umask 002
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

So if you use `creat()` with a file permission of `0777`, you will get a new file with `rwxrwxrx`. Usual programs however use `0666`as file permission argument for `creat()`.